# is it possible to make a @Aspect request scope in spring

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

is it possible to make a @Aspect request scope in spring? Because it seems that it doesn't work, and it kind of makes sense; the proxy object isn't actually injected anywhere, the advice is just applied by the runtime. Just wondering...

Example:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    // expecting this to get autowired per request
    @Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Around(...)
    public void doSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        // something here
        pjp.proceed();
        // something there
    }
}
```

And in XML:

```
<bean class="MyAspect" scope="request" />
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @Cygnusx1: edited question with example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using an aspect, implement `HandlerInterceptor`.  Then you have simple access to all of the usual objects, including the Request, and have pre and post handle methods.

Comment: I ended up making the aspect a singleton bean and injecting a separate request scope bean that was holding the autowired HttpServletRequest. But your answer works too.