# Request scoped Spring AOP advice is called twice

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I have a Spring AOP aspect (Spring Boot 2.1) that should be instantiated per request, because I want to inject the current user per request (instead of using a ThreadLocal). But if I make my aspect request scoped with `@RequestScope` the advice is applied twice!

The aspect class looks like this:

```
@Component
@RequestScope // without this annotation the aspect is applied only once
@Aspect
class MyAscpect { ... }
```

I'm using it with Jersey (JAX-RS), but I think that should not matter here.

How can I prevent duplicate application of the advice?

Comment: I am not a Spring user, only an AOP expert. So I am not sure if request-scoped aspects are even supported. The Spring manual does not mention it. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7194899/1082681) you could implement a `HandlerInterceptor` instead of an aspect or inject a request-scoped object into your singleton aspect.

Comment: Request scoped beans cannot be injected into singletons. [Related question](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton). Unfortunately a `HandlerInterceptor` is no option, because I don't use Spring MVC.